# Bat command call .txt

Tags: batch-file

I need to know how or what do I have to enter on

```
for /f %%a in (C:\communitylist.txt) do call :LOOP %%a 
:LOOP 
start myCommand 
timeout 20
goto :LOOP
```

How do I make it jump to the next line of the txt?

Right now it stuck on the first line from txt

In the txt file I have a code on first line, a second code on the second line and so on

Comment: but you have created an endless loop.And goto breaks the `FOR` context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace `goto :LOOP` with `goto :eof`, which ends your "subroutine" and continues with the `for`command.